Where am I going wrong in my understanding of group theory and the orthogonal group?
I was reading a research paper in which one of the claims is as follows:

If there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the stabilizer of $x$ is contained in the kernel of $\rho$, then there are infinitely many $\rho$-intertwining solutions. (See "Property (S3) ensures that this space is infinite dimensional; see [2].")

Some context is in order. Let $G$ be a closed subgroup of orthogonal group $O(n)$. Suppose that $\rho : G \to \mathbb{Z}_2 = \{1, -1\}$ is a continuous surjective homomorphism.
A function $u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be $\rho$-intertwining if
$$
u(gx) = \rho(g)u(x)\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n, g\in G\,.
$$
Then, the stabilizer of $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set $G_x := \{g\in G : gx = x\}$ and the above statement can be restated as follows:

If there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $G_x \subseteq \operatorname{ker}\rho$ then there are infinitely many $\rho$-intertwining functions.

However, I am worried I can construct a group $G$ and a homomorphism $\rho$ satisfying the required condition, but such that there are no $\rho$-intertwining functions. Therefore, I am likely making a mistake in my construction/understanding. If someone could explain where I am going wrong, I would appreciate it.

Set $G_0 = SO(2)\times O(n-2)$ and let $g_0 \in O(n)$ be given by
$$
g_0(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = (-x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)\,.
$$
Define $G$ to be the group generated by $G_0$ and $g_0$. Then, let $\rho$ be the homomorphism whose kernel is $G_0$. Observe that if $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is such that $x_1\ne 0$ then $g_0 \notin G_x$. It follows that $G_x \subseteq G_0 = \operatorname{ker}\rho$.
Now, if $u$ is $\rho$-intertwining then
$$
u(x) = -u(g_0x)\,.
$$
On the other hand, we can rotate $(x_1, x_2)$ in the $x_1x_2$-plane until we reach $(x_1, -x_2)$. But this means that
$$
u(x) = u(g_0 x)
$$
since rotations in the $x_1x_2$-plane are in $G_0$.
Combining, we get $u(x) = -u(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ so $u\equiv 0$.

you should give a link to the paper

@WillJagy sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039618301578 It's in the introduction a bit below stating properties (S1), (S2), (S3). "Property (S3) ensures that this space is infinite dimensional; see [2]." I updated the question accordingly.

Perhaps if you realize that $G=O(2)\times O(n-2)$, you’ll find your error. The extra factor of $O(n-2)$ just muddies the water. Just stick with $n=2$.


Observe that if $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is such that $x_1\ne 0$ then $g_0 \notin G_x$. It follows that $G_x \subseteq G_0 = \operatorname{ker}\rho$.

This isn't right. Let's assume $n = 2$ for simplicity. Then $G = O(2)$ and $G_0 = SO(2) \cong S^1$ is just the group of rotations, which acts freely on the nonzero points of the plane, so $G_x \cap G_0 = \{1\}$ for all nonzero $x$. In fact for any $n \ge 2$ and any $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ there is always a reflection in the $x_1x_2$-plane that fixes $x$, so $G_x$ is not contained in $SO(2) \times O(n-2)$.

I suppose that for a natural number $m$, $O(m)$ is the group of orthogonal matrices of order $n$, and $SO(m)$ be a subgroup of $O(m)$ consisting of the matrices with the determinant $1$.

On the other hand, we can rotate $(x_1, x_2)$ in the $x_1x_2$-plane until we reach $(x_1, -x_2)$. But this means that $$u(x) = u(g_0 x)$$
since rotations in the $x_1x_2$-plane are in $G_0$.

I do not see why we have the conclusion. Indeed, let $r$ be the rotation of the $x_1x_2$-plane such that $r(x_1, x_2)=(x_1,-x_2)$. Then $$u((r\times 1_{O(n-2)})(x))=\rho((r\times 1_{O(n-2)}))u(x)=u(x),$$ but $r\times 1_{O(n-2)}\ne g_0$.

The idea would be that $r(x_1, x_2) = (-x_1, x_2)$. So, even though $r\times 1_{O(n-2)}\ne g_0$, we have $[r\times 1_{O(n-2)}]x = g_0x$. Thus, $u(x) = u([r\times 1_{O(n-2)}]x)$ by the $\rho$-intertwining property so $u(x) = u(g_0x)$
